# Can we use existing AWS EC2 instance with Databricks?

Tags: databricks

We are planning to opt for Databricks with AWS in our project. I know that Databricks use AWS Ec2 instances for computation. The problem here is that we already have reserved Ec2 instances and like to utilize the same with databricks. So, is there any way to attach the same with databricks?

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old, so the answer today may differ from how reservations worked in 2018. Today, it depends on the kind of reservation you are using: capacity reservation, savings plans, zonal or regional reservations, etc. For reference:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-capacity-reservations.html#capacity-reservations-differences

In general EC2 doesn't care about *what* launched the instance when it considers what is reserved vs on-demand, so long as what you are running matches the attributes of your reservation: it simply looks at your reservation, compares that to your running instances, and if any instances match your reservation, EC2 will treat those instances as such, regardless if these instances were launched by the AWS Console, SDK, CLI, Databricks, etc.

For example, If you reserved 4 m5.xlarge instances, and you have 2 such instances running that you launched yourself, and then Databricks launches 4 more of these on-demand, then you would have 4 instances that EC2 considers reserved and 2 instances which are on-demand. However, this is contingent on that your reservation matches the attributes that Databricks uses when launching an instance: more details than the instance family are required for a capacity reservation, such as the operating system, for example.